# In what order are the static constructors of parent and child classes called?

Tags: .net, static-constructor

In what order are the static constructors of parent and child classes called?

```
class A     { static A() { MessageBox.Show("Yaht"); } }
class B : A { static B() { MessageBox.Show("Zee");  } }
class C : A { static C() { MessageBox.Show("Zey");  } }

static void Main()
{
    B b = new B();
    C c = new C();
}
```

I could test it right now... if I had a compiler available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Output:

```
Zee
Yaht
Zey
```

..........

Comment: +1, I get the same behaviour. Now, why? Wouldn't it make more sense for the parent static constructors to be called first? What if B referenced some static field in A that wasn't initialized yet?

Comment: In that case, A's static constructor will run before the field is referenced.

Comment: Actually, I was hoping the parent's static constructor could be called more than once.

Comment: The static constructor is only run the _first_ time the class is accessed—in this case when A's instance constructor is called from B's instance constructor.